# Openai semantic search not working with the file parameter

Tags: search, openai-api

From what I understand, you can use the `documents` parameter OR the `file` parameter to tell openai on what labels you want to perform a search.  I'm getting expected results using the `documents` parameter.  I am getting unsatisfactory results using the `file` parameter.  I would expect them to be the same.

When performing a search using the `documents` parameter..

```
response = dict(openai.Engine('davinci').search(
    query='sitcom',
    #file=file_id,
    max_rerank=5,
    documents=["white house", "school", "seinfeld"],
    return_metadata=False))
```

..I get expected results.. "sitcom" wins the search with a score of 771.

```
{'object': 'list', 'data': [<OpenAIObject search_result at 0xb5e8ef48> JSON: {
  "document": 0,
  "object": "search_result",
  "score": 147.98
}, <OpenAIObject search_result at 0xb5ebd148> JSON: {
  "document": 1,
  "object": "search_result",
  "score": 211.021
}, <OpenAIObject search_result at 0xb5ebd030> JSON: {
  "document": 2,
  "object": "search_result",
  "score": 771.348
}], 'model': 'davinci:2020-05-03'}
```

Now trying with the `file` parameter I create a `temp.jsonl` file with contents..

```
{"text": "white house", "metadata": "metadata here"}
{"text": "school", "metadata": "metadata here"}
{"text": "seinfeld", "metadata": "metadata here"}
```

I then upload the file to openai server with..

```
res = openai.File.create(file=open('temp.jsonl'), purpose="search")
```

where..

```
file_id = res['id']
```

I wait until the file is processed by the server then..

```
response = dict(openai.Engine('davinci').search(
    query='sitcom',
    file=file_id,
    max_rerank=5,
    #documents=["white house", "school", "seinfeld"],
    return_metadata=False))
```

But I get the following message when I perform search..

```
No similar documents were found in file with ID 'file-LzHkASUxbDjTAWBhHxHpIOf4'.Please upload more documents or adjust your query.
```

I only get results when my query exactly matches a label..

```
response = dict(openai.Engine('davinci').search(
    query='seinfeld',
    file=file_id,
    max_rerank=5,
    #documents=["white house", "school", "seinfeld"],
    return_metadata=False))

{'object': 'list', 'data': [<OpenAIObject search_result at 0xb5e74f48> JSON: {
  "document": 0,
  "object": "search_result",
  "score": 668.846,
  "text": "seinfeld"
}], 'model': 'davinci:2020-05-03'}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't the results be the same using the `documents` parameter or the `file` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rereading the docs, it seems, when using `file` parameter instead of `documents` parameter, the server first performs a basic "keyword" search with the provided `query` to narrow down the results before finally reranking those results with a semantic search using the same `query`.

This is disappointing.

Just to provide a working example..

```
{"text": "stairway to the basement", "metadata": "metadata here"}
{"text": "school", "metadata": "metadata here"}
{"text": "stairway to heaven", "metadata": "metadata here"}
```

Now using the query "led zeppelin's most famous song stairway" the server will narrow down the results to document 0 and document 2 finding matches for the "stairway" token.  It will then perform a semantic search and score both of them.  Document 2 ("stairway to heaven") will have the highest relevancy score.

Using the query "stairway to the underground floor" will give document 0 ("stairway to the basement") the highest relevancy score.

This is disappointing because the query has to be useful for both a keyword search AND the semantic search.

In my original post, the keyword search was not providing any results because the query was only designed for a semantic search.  When using the `documents` parameter, only a semantic search is performed, that is why it worked in that case.